# Comparator gives data in wrong order

Tags: java, android, arraylist, kotlin, comparator

I have an ArrayList of Pojo Object called classWiseArrayList. One of the field of Pojo Object is average. I need to show the arraylist in ascending order.

Here is my Pojo Class

```
data class ClassWiseData(
        @SerializedName("class_id")
        @Expose
        val classId: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("class_code")
        @Expose
        val classCode: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("average")
        @Expose
        val average: String? = null)
```

Here is my code

```
 classWiseArrayList.sortWith(
                Comparator { o1, o2 -> o1?.average!!.compareTo(o2?.average!!) })
```

The sorting works fine when none of the average is equal to 100, but if one of the average is 100, the 100 average comes at the top instead at the bottom.

What mistake am I doing?

Comment: What is the type of `average`?

Comment: @yole It is String

Comment: Strings are compared alphabetically, and `100` comes earlier than `59` when sorted alphabetically. You need to compare averages as numbers and convert them to strings later.

Comment: @yole ok will give it a try

Comment: @yole Thanks it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare numbers using String comparison (e.g. "86" is alphabetically higher than "100"). Try to convert **average** to a number (i.e. Int) and use some numeric comparator instead.

E.g.:

```
listOf<ClassWiseData>().sortedBy { it.average?.toIntOrNull() }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 classWiseArrayList.sortWith(
                Comparator { o1, o2 ->
                val a1 = o1.average!!.toInt()
                val a2 = o2.average!!.toInt()
                    a1.compareTo(a2)
                })
```

Credit goes to @yole

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparator { o1, o2 ->
        o1.length.compareTo(o2.length).let {
            when(it) {
                0 -> o1.compareTo(o2)
                else -> it
            }
        }
    }
```

This comparator will work.

First it finds if strings' length are equal and then sort them.